# Creating new buffer with space in buffer name under Emacs 24.3

Tags: emacs

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3 under Windows. At work I have to conform to specific file-naming standards, some of which include spaces in the file name.

How do I create a file with a space in the file name in Emacs? I can easily open them for editing, but can't find any info on how to create one. (i.e., create the file `C:\temp\foo bar.txt`)?

## Update

In response to the question in the comments under the accepted answer: I'm using `ido-mode`, and this is the cause of the specific issue I was experiencing at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the Windows version to test, but with the Linux version, there is no particular issue. I can open a file with spaces in it and save it with these two commands:

```
C-x C-f ~/tmp/this is a test.txt
C-x C-s
```

Note that `C-x C-f` does not require an existing file. When you do `C-x C-s`, it automatically creates it.

I hope for you that this is the same behaviour with the Windows version...

Comment: On the off chance that you're using `ido-mode`, `ido-find-file` won't play nice with spaces in the file name.  You can get back to regular `find-file` with `C-x C-f C-f`.

Comment: @Dan - You got the issue in one...as soon as I read julienc's post, I realized it had to be an ido issue, even before I saw your comment. Thanks all!

Comment: Great!  Also, I just learned this from Drew's answer, but you can also quote the space with `C-q SPC` in `ido-find-file`.

Comment: `SPC` is a poor choice for a completion key. During completion, having `SPC` do anything other than self-insert by default makes little sense, IMO. It took decades to get this accepted for file-name completion in GNU Emacs. It might take decades more to get it accepted for non-file-name completion as well. And perhaps more decades still to get it accepted for Ido also...

Answer (score 3):

In Emacs you **create** a file the same way you **open** it for editing: `C-x C-f c:/temp/foo bar.txt` (no need for backslashes in Emacs).

And in Emacs 24.3 you can just type spaces like any other file-name chars. (In old Emacs versions you needed to quote `SPC` chars by preceding them with `C-q`: `C-q SPC` inserts a space char.)

(Actually, that just creates a new buffer for the new file (the buffer "visits" the file).  The file itself is created when you save the buffer: `C-x C-s`.)